# precise timing in C

Tags: c, linux, time

I have a little code below. I use this code to output some 1s and 0s (`unsigned output[38]`) from a GPIO of an embedded board.

My Question: the time between two output values (1, 0 or 0, 1) should be **416 microseconds** as I define on `clock_nanosleep` below code, I also used `sched_priority()` for a better time resolution. However, an oscilloscope (pic below) measurement shows that the time between the two output values are **770 usec** . I wonder why do I have that much inaccuracy between the signals?

PS.  the board(beagleboard) has Linux 3.2.0-23-omap #36-Ubuntu Tue Apr 10 20:24:21 UTC 2012 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux kernel, and it has 750 MHz CPU, `top` shows almost no CPU(~1%) and memory(~0.5%) is consumed before I run my code. I use an electronic oscilloscope which has no calibration problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //exit();
#include <sched.h>
#include <time.h>

void msg_send();
struct sched_param sp;

int main(void){
      sp.sched_priority = sched_get_priority_max(SCHED_FIFO);
      sched_setscheduler(0, SCHED_FIFO, &sp);
      msg_send();
    return 0;
}

void msg_send(){
    unsigned output[38] = {0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1}; 

    FILE *fp8;
    if ((fp8 = fopen("/sys/class/gpio/export", "w")) == NULL){  //echo 139 > export
           fprintf(stderr,"Cannot open export file: line844.\n"); fclose(fp8);exit(1);
    }
    fprintf(fp8, "%d", 139);  //pin 3
    fclose(fp8);

    if ((fp8 = fopen("/sys/class/gpio/gpio139/direction", "rb+")) == NULL){
       fprintf(stderr,"Cannot open direction file - GPIO139 - line851.\n");fclose(fp8); exit(1);
    }
    fprintf(fp8, "out");
    fclose(fp8);

   if((fp8 = fopen("/sys/class/gpio/gpio139/value", "w")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"error in openning value\n");  fclose(fp8); exit(1);
}

struct timespec req = { .tv_sec=0, .tv_nsec = 416000 }; //416 usec

/* here is the part that my question focus*/
    while(1){
        for(i=0;i<38;i++){
        rewind(fp8);
        fprintf(fp8, "%d", output[i]);
        clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC ,0, &req, NULL);

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**EDIT:** I have been reading for days that clock_nanosleep() or other nanosleep, usleep etc. does not guarantee the waking up on time. they usually provide to sleep the code for the defined time, but waking up the process depends on the CPU. what I found is that absolute time provides a better resolution (`TIMER_ABSTIME` flag). I found the same solution as Maxime suggests. however, I have a glitch on my signal when for loop is finalized. In my opinion, it is not good to any sleep functions to create a PWM or data output on an embedded platform. It is good to spend some time to learn CPU timers that platforms provide to generate the PWM or data out that has good accuracy.

Comment: You should put your solution in a proper answer (you are allowed to answer your own question) and accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't figure out how a call to clock_getres() can solve your problem. In the man page, it's said that only read the resolution of the clock.

As Geoff said, using absolute sleeping clock should be a better solution. This can avoid the unespected timing delay from other code.

```
struct timespec Time;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &(Time));

while(1){
    Time.tv_nsec += 416000;
    if(Time.tv_nsec > 999999999){
        (Time.tv_sec)++;
        Time.tv_nsec -= 1000000000;
    }
    clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_REALTIME, TIMER_ABSTIME, &(Time), NULL);
    //Do something
}
```

I am using this on fews programs I have for generating some regular message on ethernet network. And it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing time sensitive I/O, you probably shouldn't use the stuff in `stdio.h` but instead the I/O system calls because of the buffering done by stdio. It looks like you might be getting the worst effect of the buffering too because your program does these steps:

1. fill the buffer
2. sleep
3. rewind, which I believe will flush the buffer

What you want is for the kernel to service the write while you are sleeping, instead the buffer is flushed after you sleep and you have to wait for the kernel to process it.

I think your best bet is to use `open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio139/value", O_WRONLY|O_DIRECT)` to minimize delays due to caching.

if you still need to flush buffers to force the write through you probably want to use `clock_gettime` to compute the time spent flushing the data and subtract that from the sleep time. Alternatively add the desired interval to the result of `clock_gettime` and pass that to `clock_nanosleep` and use the `TIMER_ABSTIME` flag to wait for that absolute time to occur.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the problem is that the `clock_nanosleep` is sleeping for 416 microsec
and that the other commands in the loop as well as the loop and `clock_nanosleep` architecture itself are taking 354 microsec. The OS may also be making demands.

What interval do you get if you set the sleep = 0?

Are you running this on a computer or a PLC?

**Response to Comment**

Seems like you have something somewher in the hardware/software that is doing something unexpected - it could be a bugger to find.

I have 2 suggestions depending on how critical the period is:

1. Low criticality - put a figure in your program that causes the loop to take the time you want. However, if this is a transient or time/temperature dependant effect you will need to check for drift periodically.
2. High criticality - Build a temperature stable oscilator in hardware. These can be bought off the shelf.

Comment: I run it on an embedded board that runs linux. I removed the ´clock_nanosleep´ line in the ´while(1)´ loop to see how much time does it take to perform ´rewind()´, ´fprintf()´ and ´for()´ on that loop. it takes 11.1 nanoseconds. the weird thing is that if 20 is assigned to ´tv_nsec´, then the time between two values are 102 nanoseconds..