# simplest truest timing in C

Tags: c, time, microcontroller, usleep

I'm making a microcontroller programmer and for now, I've been using `usleep()` to try to introduce appropriate delays.

It seems that sometimes the program works and sometimes it doesn't.

I tried the `-O2` flag when compiling my code but I begin to wonder if that's a mistake.

Also, is there a more accurate timing function I can use besides `usleep()` that doesn't involve any libraries not included in the standard system?  I don't want to use a function that the system caches in the background (and screws up the timing). Heck, if it means to call a specific address in the system to wait for a clock tick, then I'd rather do that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: probably, but it fully depends on your hardware. there can't be an universal answer to that

Comment: What's the h/w and o/s we're on?

Comment: 'if it means call a specific address in the system to wait for a clock tick' well, for more accurate timing, it's usually done the other way round - the hardware calls a specific address in the system when an interval has expired.  As others have commented, you need to look at your hardware, specifically timers.

Comment: Also, 'simplest, truest' are usually mutually exclusive:(  If it were not so, everyone would use that mechanism and there would be no others to consider.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [precise timing in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765301/precise-timing-in-c)

Comment: Please define "doesn't work".   Does it wait for the wrong time (too short, too long, no time at all, forever..) ?

Answer (score 2):

probably, but it fully depends on your hardware.

On some machines you can directly read timer values at some given addresses, but there can't be an universal answer to that. Prepare to use `volatile` attribute to read those timers as they change while your program is executing.

On the more portable side, one system call which (if available) is more reliable is `nanosleep` if available on your system ([How to use nanosleep() in C? What are `tim.tv_sec` and `tim.tv_nsec`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684359/how-to-use-nanosleep-in-c-what-are-tim-tv-sec-and-tim-tv-nsec)).

It works by active/calibrated loops so when you call it, there's no system call involved (at least for small values, probably depends on the implementation).

If you don't have it, well, you could implement it by:

- calibrating a loop (at startup)
- using this calibration value to achieve desired delay

It's best to include this sleep implementation in a part which isn't optimized at all (`-O0`). You won't have nanosecond precision with that but for milliseconds you should be okay.